# how to pass a variable to lm within a function in R

Tags: r, scope, environment, lm

Here is a (non)working example of how I would like to do things.  The restriction is that all this has to happen within a function and that `K` should not be appended to `x`. What's the right way to do this? The issue is that `K` is not associated with the correct environment here.

*EDIT: based on the comments below. the answer provided works but we still don't yet understand why*

```
f = function() { K=5; x = data.frame(a=1:10, b=(1:10)^2); 
                 regstr = "b ~ a:I(a>K)";
                 lm(regstr, data=x);
                }
f()
Error in unique(c("AsIs", oldClass(x))) (from #3) : object 'K' not found 



> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
 [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
 [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Comment: Odd. It works for me.

Comment: hmm. that is weird, just pasted by session info above

Comment: Mine's the same, except on Windows x64 and locale UnitedStates.1252. Does that block of code work if run outside the function?

Comment: yes it does. it's only when it's in a function that's why i think it's something to do with environment and scoping

Answer (score 3):

```
f = function() { K=5; x = data.frame(a=1:10, b=(1:10)^2); 
                  regstr = "b ~ a:I(a>K)";
                  lm(as.formula(regstr), data=x);
}
```

you missed the

```
as.formula
```

Comment: could you explain why that works? R is perfectly ok with strings being passed to it instead of formulas in `lm`...

Comment: @Alex: Can you explain what you mean by "R is perfectly ok with strings being passed to it instead of formulas"? What you are entering in the usual `lm` incantations are _expressions_ rather than "strings".

Comment: Hi @Alex, I don't know, in the man page of lm function it is stated: "formula: an object of class ‘"formula", that is way I use as.formula, to generate an object of this class. The important is to pay attention to the correct formula syntax.

Comment: @DWin: I just meant that you can run the following in R easily:
`x = 1:10; y=10:1; a = "x ~ y"; lm(a)`. you don't have to pass a `formula` as long as your string is coercible to a fomula.

Comment: I say again (in more R-centric language) .... what you are calling a "string" is NOT a character vector. This would NOT succeed: `lm("b ~ a:I(a>K)", data=x)`

Comment: @DWin: alright, then why does the code in my previous comment work? is `a` not a character vector there? moreover, in the case that i am wrong (which I probably am as you are certainly more experienced), could you explain why my code in the question does not work since it follows the same strategy is the code in the comment?

Comment: I was wrong and you were right about the coercion of characters to formulas in `lm`. In your case this works: "b ~ a:I(x$a>K)". And I think it is because the `I` function does not use the same evaluation environment as the rest of the formula evaluation process.

Comment: ok -- the interesting thing is the answer that user provided works which doesn't square with your intuition here.